# Issue while working in server asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have an web application name travel. Every thing is working fine while working in test database even if i connect it to live database it works fine in local server but not working in live server.for ex.. I have a grid view to show the details where i can insert,delete,update and view but its working fine in my local server but in live server, my file are updating for the first time but if i try to update for the second time its not working. I have no idea whats happening can any one help me in this.

***travel.cs***

```
protected void gv_food_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv_food.ShowFooter = true;
    gv_food.EditIndex = -1;
    Loadgv_food();
}

protected void gv_food_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        AddConfirmDelete((GridView)sender, e);
        hdnAmtvalue.Value = Convert.ToString((e.Row.RowIndex + 1) + (gv_food.PageSize * gv_food.PageIndex));
        hdnAmtvalue.Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(hdnAmtvalue.Value) + 3);
    }


    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {

        DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("drpfood");
        sqlq = "SELECT ':Select:' AS DESCRIPTION,0 AS regionid FROM dual";
        sqlq += "\n UNION";
        sqlq += "\n select DESCRIPTION,regionid from regionmaster";
        ds = db.fillDataset(sqlq);
        drp.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        drp.DataTextField = "description";
        drp.DataValueField = "regionid";
        drp.DataBind();

        DropDownList drpC = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("drp_currency");
        sqlq = "SELECT 0 AS CURRENCYID,':Select:' AS DESCRIPTION FROM dual";
        sqlq += "\n UNION";
        sqlq += "\n select CURRENCYID,DESCRIPTION from currencymaster";

        ds1 = db.fillDataset(sqlq);

        drpC.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        drpC.DataTextField = "description";
        drpC.DataValueField = "currencyid";
        drpC.DataBind();
        drpC.SelectedIndex = 2;

        Load_CurrencyRate();

        DropDownList ddlcurrency = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("drp_currency");
        int foodamt = Convert.ToInt32(hdnAmtvalue.Value);
        TextBox ticketamount = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtamount");
        TextBox inrate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_inrrate");
        TextBox dollarrate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_dollarrate");
        TextBox inramount = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_inramount");
        TextBox dollaramount = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_dollaramount");
        TextBox txtdate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtfromdate");
        ticketamount.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return chkNumber()");
        dollarrate.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return chkNumber()");
        inrate.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return chkNumber()");
        ticketamount.Attributes.Add("ontextchange", "Calculateticketfood(" + (e.Row.RowIndex + foodamt) + ")");
        ddlcurrency.Attributes.Add("onchange", "Calculateticketfood(" + (e.Row.RowIndex + foodamt) + ")");
        ticketamount.Attributes.Add("Onkeyup", "Calculateticketfood(" + (e.Row.RowIndex + foodamt) + ")");
        inrate.Attributes.Add("Onkeyup", "Calculateticketfood(" + (e.Row.RowIndex + foodamt) + ")");
        dollarrate.Attributes.Add("Onkeyup", "Calculateticketfood(" + (e.Row.RowIndex + foodamt) + ")");

        inramount.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        dollaramount.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        txtdate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        //inrate.Text = hdnAdvInrRate.Value.ToString();
        inrate.Text = hdnAdvUsdRate.Value.ToString();
        dollarrate.Text = hdnAdvUsdRate.Value.ToString();
        //ddlcurrency.SelectedIndex = ddlcurrency.Items.IndexOf(ddlcurrency.Items.FindByText(hdnAdvCurrency.Value));
        drp.SelectedIndex = drp.Items.IndexOf(drp.Items.FindByText(hdnRegion.Value));
    }
}
protected void gv_food_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    sql = "delete from tmpintfoodexpenses where detailid=" + gv_food.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString() + "";
    db.Executecommand(sql);
    gv_food.EditIndex = -1;
    gv_food.ShowFooter = true;
    Loadgv_food();
    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Successfully deleted');</script>");
    lblFoodException.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully deleted";

}
protected void gv_food_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    lblFoodException.Text = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        gv_food.ShowFooter = false;
        gv_food.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        Loadgv_food();

        //changes made on 25/jan/2012
        DropDownList drp1 = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drpEhr1");
        DropDownList drp2 = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drpEmin1");
        DropDownList drp3 = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drpEahr1");
        DropDownList drp4 = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drpEamin1");
        sql = "select  ARRIVALTIME,DEPATURETIME from tmpintfoodexpenses where headid='" + Label22.Text + "'and  EmpId=" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + " and EmpType='" + Session["EmployeeType"].ToString() + "'";
        //ds1 = db.fillDataset(sql);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = db.fillTable(sql);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["DEPATURETIME"].ToString().Contains(":"))
            {
                string[] _dhhmm = dt.Rows[0]["DEPATURETIME"].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { ':' });
                if (_dhhmm[0].Trim() != null)
                {
                    drp1.SelectedIndex = drp1.Items.IndexOf(drp1.Items.FindByText(_dhhmm[0].ToString()));
                    drp2.SelectedIndex = drp1.Items.IndexOf(drp1.Items.FindByText(_dhhmm[1].ToString()));
                }
                if (dt.Rows[0]["ARRIVALTIME"].ToString().Contains(":"))
                {
                    string[] _ahhmm = dt.Rows[0]["ARRIVALTIME"].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    if (_ahhmm[0].Trim() != null)
                    {
                        drp3.SelectedIndex = drp1.Items.IndexOf(drp1.Items.FindByText(_ahhmm[0].ToString()));
                        drp4.SelectedIndex = drp1.Items.IndexOf(drp1.Items.FindByText(_ahhmm[1].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //End

        sql = "select currencydescription,foodorperdiems from tmpintfoodexpenses where headid='" + Label22.Text + "'and  EmpId=" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + " and EmpType='" + Session["EmployeeType"].ToString() + "'";
        ds1 = db.fillDataset(sql);
        currflag = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

        DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drpefood");
        sql = "SELECT ':Select:' AS DESCRIPTION,0 AS regionid FROM dual";
        sql += "\n UNION";
        sql += "\n select description,regionid from regionmaster";
        setDataSource(drp, sql);
        DropDownList ddlFood = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddlFoodOrPerdiems");
        ddlFood.SelectedValue = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        Label lblregion = (Label)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lblf");
        lblregion.Visible = false;
        drp.SelectedIndex = (drp.Items.IndexOf(drp.Items.FindByText(lblregion.Text.ToString())));

        DropDownList drpC = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drp_ecurrency");
        sqlq = "SELECT 0 AS CURRENCYID,':Select:' AS DESCRIPTION FROM dual";
        sqlq += "\n UNION";
        sqlq += "\n select CURRENCYID,DESCRIPTION from currencymaster";
        ds1 = db.fillDataset(sqlq);
        drpC.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        drpC.DataTextField = "description";
        drpC.DataValueField = "currencyid";
        drpC.DataBind();

        drpC.SelectedIndex = drpC.Items.IndexOf(drpC.Items.FindByText(currflag));

        indexrow = gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].RowIndex.ToString();
        rowindex = int.Parse(indexrow);
        rowindex = rowindex + 2;

        DropDownList ddlcurrency = (DropDownList)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drp_ecurrency");
        TextBox ticketamount = (TextBox)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txtUamount");
        TextBox inrate = (TextBox)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txt_einrrate");
        TextBox dollarrate = (TextBox)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txt_edollarrate");
        TextBox inramount = (TextBox)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txt_einramount");
        TextBox dollaramount = (TextBox)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txt_edollaramount");
        TextBox txtdate = (TextBox)gv_food.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txtUfromdate");
        ticketamount.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return chkNumber()");
        dollarrate.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return chkNumber()");
        inrate.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return chkNumber()");
        ddlcurrency.Attributes.Add("onchange", "Calculatefoodedit(" + rowindex + ")");
        ticketamount.Attributes.Add("Onkeyup", "Calculatefoodedit(" + rowindex + ")");
        inrate.Attributes.Add("Onkeyup", "Calculatefoodedit(" + rowindex + ")");
        dollarrate.Attributes.Add("Onkeyup", "Calculatefoodedit(" + rowindex + ")");
        inramount.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        dollaramount.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        txtdate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
protected void gv_food_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    indexrow = "";
    rowindex = 0;
    GridViewRow row1 = gv_food.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox tfromdate = row1.FindControl("txtUfromdate") as TextBox;
    TextBox ttodate = row1.FindControl("txtUtodate") as TextBox;
    DropDownList ddlfood = (DropDownList)row1.FindControl("ddlFoodOrPerdiems");
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row1.FindControl("drpefood");
    TextBox txtdescription = row1.FindControl("txtUdescription") as TextBox;
    TextBox txtreference = row1.FindControl("txtUreference") as TextBox;
    TextBox tAmt = row1.FindControl("txtUAmount") as TextBox;
    //DropDownList drpccy = (DropDownList)row1.FindControl("drpEccy") as DropDownList;
    Label tid = row1.FindControl("lblEid") as Label;
    DropDownList drpccy = (DropDownList)row1.FindControl("drpEccy") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList eddl_curr = (DropDownList)row1.FindControl("drp_ecurrency");
    TextBox edcurrentrate = (TextBox)row1.FindControl("txt_edollarrate");
    TextBox edamount = (TextBox)row1.FindControl("txt_edollaramount");
    TextBox eicurrentrate = (TextBox)row1.FindControl("txt_einrrate");
    TextBox eiamount = (TextBox)row1.FindControl("txt_einramount");
    //changes made on 25/jan/2012
    TextBox txtENoOfDays = row1.FindControl("txtENoOfDays") as TextBox;
    DropDownList drpEhr1 = row1.FindControl("drpEhr1") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList drpEmin1 = row1.FindControl("drpEmin1") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList drpEahr1 = row1.FindControl("drpEahr1") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList drpEamin1 = row1.FindControl("drpEamin1") as DropDownList;
    //End
    if (tfromdate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the From Date');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Enter the From Date";
        tfromdate.Focus();
        return;
    }
    //changes made on 25/jan/2012
    if (drpEhr1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Select the Depature Hours.";
        drpEhr1.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (drpEmin1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Select the Depature Minute.";
        drpEmin1.Focus();
        return;
    }
    //End
    if (ttodate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the To Date');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Enter the To Date";
        ttodate.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (drpEahr1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Select the Arrival Hours.";
        drpEahr1.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (drpEamin1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Select the Arrival Minue.";
        drpEahr1.Focus();
        return;
    }
    //End
    if (ddlfood.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Select the Food or Perdiems');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Select the Food or Perdiems";
        ddl.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (ddl.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Select the region');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Select the region";
        ddl.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (txtdescription.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the Description');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Enter the Description";
        txtdescription.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (txtreference.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the Reference');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Enter the Reference";
        txtreference.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (eddl_curr.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the Currencyid');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully Updated";
        eddl_curr.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (edcurrentrate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the amount');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully Updated";
        edcurrentrate.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (edamount.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the amount');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully Updated";
        edamount.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (eicurrentrate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the amount');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully Updated";
        eicurrentrate.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (eiamount.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Enter the amount');</script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully Updated";
        eiamount.Focus();
        return;
    }
    //changes made on 25/jan/2012
    if (Convert.ToInt32(drpEhr1.SelectedItem.Text) >= 12)
    {
        Ehh = "PM";
    }
    else
    {
        Ehh = "AM";
    }
    if (Convert.ToInt32(drpEahr1.SelectedItem.Text) >= 12)
    {
        Emm = "PM";
    }
    else
    {
        Emm = "AM";
    }
    DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(tfromdate.Text.ToString() + " " + drpEhr1.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower() + ":" + drpEmin1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + " " + Ehh);
    DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(ttodate.Text.ToString() + " " + drpEahr1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + ":" + drpEamin1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + " " + Emm);
    tp1 = t2.Subtract(t1);
    string[] EgetInfo = Convert.ToString(tp1).Split(new char[] { '.' });
    if (EgetInfo.Length > 1) // Day calculating
    {
        Enodays = EgetInfo[0];
        string[] EgetHours = EgetInfo[1].ToString().Split(new char[] { ':' });

        if (Convert.ToInt32(EgetHours[0].ToString()) >= 6 && Convert.ToInt32(EgetHours[0].ToString()) < 12)
        {
            EtotalDays = Convert.ToDouble(EgetInfo[0].ToString()) + 0.50;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(EgetHours[0].ToString()) >= 12)
        {
            EtotalDays = Convert.ToDouble(EgetInfo[0].ToString()) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            EtotalDays = Convert.ToDouble(EgetInfo[0].ToString());
        }
        EtotTime = Ehh.ToString() + ":" + Emm.ToString() + " PM";

        EtotTime = Ehh.ToString() + ":" + Emm.ToString() + " AM";

    }
    else//Hours Calculating
    {
        string[] EgetHours = EgetInfo[0].ToString().Split(new char[] { ':' });
        Enodays = "0";
        hh = EgetHours[0];
        mm = EgetHours[1];
        if (Convert.ToInt32(hh.ToString()) >= 6 && Convert.ToInt32(hh.ToString()) < 12)
        {
            EtotalDays = 0.50;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(hh.ToString()) >= 12)
        {
            EtotalDays = 1;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(hh.ToString().Length) > 12)
        {
            EtotTime = hh.ToString() + ":" + mm.ToString() + " PM";
        }
        else
        {
            EtotTime = hh.ToString() + ":" + mm.ToString() + " AM";
        }
    }
    txtENoOfDays.Text = Convert.ToString(EtotalDays);
    //End
    sqlq = "select min(traveldate),max(dateofreturn) from tmpinttravelclaimsdetail where headid='" + Label22.Text + "'and EmpId=" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + " and EmpType='" + Session["EmployeeType"].ToString() + "'";
    ds3 = db.fillDataset(sqlq);
    if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        fromdate = ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        todate = ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    }
    string from = Convert.ToDateTime(tfromdate.Text).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
    string to = Convert.ToDateTime(ttodate.Text).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
    //string date = Convert.ToDateTime(tfromdate.Text).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
    bool x = ((Convert.ToDateTime(from) >= Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate)) && (Convert.ToDateTime(to) <= Convert.ToDateTime(todate)));
    if (x == false)
    {
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ma", "<script> alert('Date should be between departure date and arrival date '); </script>");
        lblFoodException.Text = "* Date should be between departure date and arrival date";
        tfromdate.Text = "";
        return;
    }
    bool y = (Convert.ToDateTime(from) <= Convert.ToDateTime(todate));
    if (y == false)
    {
        //    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ma", "<script> alert('invalid date '); </script>");
        tfromdate.Text = "";
        lblFoodException.Text = "Invalid Date";
        return;
    }
    int curr8 = 1;
    //Poovaragavan P changes made on 25/jan/2012
    sqlq = "select min(DEPATURETIME),max(ARRIVALTIME),min(traveldate),max(dateofreturn) from tmpinttravelclaimsdetail where headid='" + Label22.Text + "'and EmpId=" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + " and EmpType='" + Session["EmployeeType"].ToString() + "'";
    ds5 = db.fillDataset(sqlq);
    if (ds5.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        EDepTime = ds5.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        EArrTime = ds5.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        EDepDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ds5.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
        EArrDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ds5.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    if (EDepDate == Convert.ToDateTime(from.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") && EArrDate.ToString() == Convert.ToDateTime(to.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyy"))
    {
        if ((EDepTime != drpEhr1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + ":" + drpEmin1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()) || (EArrTime != drpEahr1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + ":" + drpEamin1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()))
        {
            lblFoodException.Text = "Time should be Equal to departure Time and arrival Time";
            lblFoodException.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            drpEhr1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpEmin1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpEahr1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpEamin1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            drpEhr1.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
    //End
    sql = " Update tmpintfoodexpenses set Expensedate=to_Date('" + tfromdate.Text + "','dd/mon/yyyy'),";
    sql += " Expensetodate=to_Date('" + ttodate.Text + "','dd/mon/yyyy'),";
    sql += "  FOODORPERDIEMS='" + ddlfood.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',";
    sql += "  region=" + ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + ",";
    sql += " DESCRIPTION='" + mod.checkforapostrophe(txtdescription.Text) + "',";
    sql += " REFERENCE='" + mod.checkforapostrophe(txtreference.Text) + "',";
    sql += " amount=" + mod.checkforapostrophe(tAmt.Text) + ",";
    sql += " Currencyid=" + eddl_curr.SelectedItem.Value + ",";
    sql += " currencydescription='" + mod.checkforapostrophe(eddl_curr.SelectedItem.Text) + "',";
    sql += " dollarcurrentrate=" + mod.checkforapostrophe(edcurrentrate.Text) + ",";
    sql += " dollaramount=" + mod.checkforapostrophe(edamount.Text) + ",";
    sql += " inrcurrentrate=" + mod.checkforapostrophe(eicurrentrate.Text) + ",";
    sql += " inramount=" + mod.checkforapostrophe(eiamount.Text) + ",";
    //Poovaragavan P changes made on 25/jan/2012  
    sql += " NOOFDAYS='" + mod.checkforapostrophe(txtENoOfDays.Text) + "',";
    sql += " ARRIVALTIME='" + drpEahr1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + ":" + drpEamin1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "',";
    sql += " DEPATURETIME='" + drpEhr1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + ":" + drpEmin1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "',";
    sql += " TOTALTIME='" + EtotTime.ToString() + "'";
    //End
    sql += " where detailid =" + mod.checkforapostrophe(tid.Text) + "";
    db.Executecommand(sql);
    gv_food.EditIndex = -1;
    gv_food.ShowFooter = true;
    Loadgv_halting();
    Loadgv_ticket();
    Loadgv_local();
    Loadgv_other();
    Loadgv_food();
    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "add", "<script>alert('Successfully Updated');</script>");
    lblFoodException.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblFoodException.Text = "* Successfully Updated";
}
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I am sorry my code is too large that's why i am unable to post